# Excel VBA for Vlookup

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am new to VBA and normally source VBA codes from online to automate manual works. I am looking for VBA code for  vlookup. I have recorded a macro with column contains 356 line of records, but when I run the macro next time with less number of rows. It still look up for 356. How do I lookup only for the cells which has values in reference cell. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you didn't post your code here, all I can do is guess what you are trying to do.  You probably need to find the last used row before implementing your vlookup methodology.  Something like this should help.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[-5]:C[-4],2,FALSE)"
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F1:F" & LastRow)

End Sub
```